# SAS - XML Libname Engine does not support processing of Data Type Definitions (DTD)

Tags: xml, sas

A simple question and I'm hoping for an easy answer.

I'm running a program in SAS and I'm getting the following warning:

```
    WARNING: DOCTYPE element encountered. The SAS XML Libname Engine does not support processing of Data Type Definitions (DTD). 
    External entity references in the document will not be resolved, and no mark up validation will be performed.
```

I am using SAS 9.3.

Has anyone had this problem and know of a way to get the SAS 9.3 XML Libname Engine working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a problem, per se.  What that's saying is that the LIBNAME XML engine does not use the DTD to validate the XML file (which is documented here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/engxml/65362/PDF/default/engxml.pdf ) and so it will not validate your data for you, even though you have a DTD specification in the file.  That's not an error, and doesn't need to be treated as such.

If you do have any actual errors, or if you are having trouble reading the file, please update the OP with additional information.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking to know. I had trouble finding documentation as to how this warning would affect my results and if there was anything I could do to fix it.